# Is there a way to set http(s) proxy for specific domain(s) system wide(on ubuntu)?

Tags: http-proxy

The requirement here is to tunnel the specific domain traffic to that proxy and rest should take the default. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For a Browser you can use the .pac file. But that does not work for client libraries which use the httpProxy environment variables only. You [set it under Network Settings in Ubuntu](http://xmodulo.com/how-to-set-up-proxy-auto-config-on-ubuntu-desktop.html).

BTW: this is really a question for superuser, serverfault or [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37306/how-do-i-configure-apt-to-use-a-proxy-pac-file).